# How to transform data into wider/pivot format in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot

I have a trade between cities. For example, London sells Cars to Liverpool at the price of 1000, while Liverpool purchases Cars from London at the price of 1100.
Also, we know the price of Bike that is sold from Manchester to Bristol (1700), but don't know the its price from Bristol to Manchester:

```
df <- data.frame (Product = c("Cars", "Cars", "Bike"),
                  Flow  = c("Sell", "Purchase", "Sell"),
                  city = c("London", "Liverpool","manchester"),
                  Destination = c("Liverpool","London","Bristol"),
                  Price = c(1000, 1100, 1700))

  Product     Flow          city      Destination    Price
1    Cars     Sell        London        Liverpool    1000
2    Cars Purchase     Liverpool           London    1100
3    Bike     Sell    Manchester          Bristol    1700
```

Now I want to reshape data and have trade time on the same line. Expected outcome:

```
  Product      city   Destination    Sell_P    Purch_P
1    Cars    London     Liverpool      1000       1100
2    Bike    Manchester   Bristol      1700        NA
```

Sell_P represents selling price from London to Liverpool, while Purch_P represents purchasing price by Liverpool from London. Price difference on the same product is caused by insurance and transportation costs

Comment: have a look at the function `pivot_wider`. What you want to do is a transformation from the "long" data format to the "wide" data format.

Comment: My question is a bit different I think

Comment: In your dataframe you do not have Manchester!

Comment: Sorry, see update

Comment: In my opinion the question is poorly phrased, because the fact that something is purchased by city from another city is conflated in table 2, resulting in loss of data. Nowhere in table 2 do we know whether Liverpool is purchasing from London or the other way around, whereas that was clear in table 1.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by the expected output, OP could you perhaps explain it a bit more. Also please only use the tidyverse tag when appropriate.

Comment: @user438383 you can see

Comment: Don't add the tag back in, the guidance on the tag wiki is clear.

Comment: But you still lose information. You don't know who's buying from who in the second table. Someone would have to read from an insurance pricing table to deduct which direction the trade was made in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it this way:

After pivoting with glueing the names, we could use the alternating behaviour of city and Destination. With grouping and filling !up and slice the first of each group we get this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Flow,
    values_from = Price, 
    names_glue = "{Flow}_P"
    ) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  fill(Purchase_P, .direction="up") %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
  Product city       Destination Sell_P Purchase_P
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Cars    London     Liverpool     1000       1100
2 Bike    Manchester Bristol       1700         NA
```